# How to intepret varnishtop output?

Tags: cache

When running.

```
varnishtop -i BereqURL
```

Output such as.

```
2.57 BereqURL url
```

Will be shown. What does the number, in this example `2.57` stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varnishtop command shows the rolling aggregate count over 60 seconds. That means even if all traffic stops, it will take 60 seconds to average down the display.

In your example:

```
2.57 BereqURL url
```

~2 requests received in the last 60 seconds for url.